# Wrap all class methods using a meta class

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, metaprogramming, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap all of the methods inside a class I wrote with a specific wrapper method.

My class inherits from the python ***dict*** class, and I want to wrap all of the methods of this parent class, such as ***__setitem__, __getitem__***, etc.

In my attempts to achieve that I have written a meta class that wraps all the methods inside it's child class, using the ***__init__*** method in the meta class, so I can access the child class's object (and not it's class definition which does not include the parent methods).

However, after running the code, I see the wrapper method is never called. Meaning the wrapping didn't succeed.

Can you help with figuring out what went wrong?

**My code:**

```py
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'wrapper.__call__()'
        res = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return wrapped

class MyMeta(type):   
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, class_dict):
        print 'meta.__init__()'
        new_class_dict = {}
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
                attr = wrapper(attr)
            new_class_dict[attr_name] = attr
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(classname, bases, new_class_dict)

class MyDict(dict):

    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print 'child.__init__()'
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args)     

d = MyDict({'key': 'value'})
d['new_key'] = 'new_value'
```

**The printout I get is:**

```
meta.__init__()
child.__init__()
```

without any reference to the **wrapper.__call__()** print I placed inside the wrapped method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the metaclass `__init__` gets called, the `class` object has already been built so modifying the attributes dict (`class_dict` in your code) at this stage is totally useless indeed. You want to use `setattr` instead:

```
class MyMeta(type):   
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, class_dict):
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            if attr_name == "__class__":
                # the metaclass is a callable attribute too, 
                # but we want to leave this one alone
                continue
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
                attr = wrapper(attr)
                setattr(cls, attr_name, attr)

        # not need for the `return` here
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(classname, bases, class_dict)
```

Comment: Hey @bruno, thanks for detailed response.
I get this error though when running (tried this way before)

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    **__class__** must be set to new-style class, not 'function' object  (the error is over the **setattr** line)

Comment: The metaclass is exposed as the `__class__` attribute, and classes are callable indeed. I updated the code snippet to avoid wrapping `__class__`. Note that there might be other __magic_methods__ you don't want to wrap either but only you can know.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I had to remove the first argument 'cls' in the  super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(cls, classname, bases, class_dict). makes sense?

Comment: And as a remark - you also need to exclude **__new__** othewise it causes other problems due to the wrapping

Comment: yes indeed the `cls` shouldn't be passed to `super().__init__()`, my bad.

Comment: This ignores any existing wrappers that are in the original class